# jQuery autocomplete working on local server but fails on web server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

The code is same on both `Web server` and `local server` but using firebug I get two kinds of response links:

Works fine

```
GET  http://localhost/www.test.co.uk/index.php/home_Controller/getSearch/r
```

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found

```
 GET   http://www.test.co.uk/index.php/home_Controller/getSearch/r"
```

And this is my JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#performsearch').keyup(function(e){

                //if key is enter stop search
                if(e.which == 13)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    var searched = $('#performsearch').val()
                    var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val() + 'index.php/home_Controller/getSearch/' + searched
                $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){
                    var elements = [];
                    $.each(result,function(i,val){
                       elements.push(val.title)
                    })
                    $('#performsearch').autocomplete({
                        source : elements
                    })

                })
            })
        })
```

Comment: Any rewrite rule on server?

Comment: I am on shared server how to check this

Comment: did you try just: /home_Controller/getSearch/r for your url

Comment: Your remote server maybe case sensitive and your local server not. Does `index.php/home_controller/getSearch/r` work?

Comment: Check if you have an .htaccess file in one of your folder (usually root folder). But seems your problem is here: var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val() + ...;   What give you alert(fullurl ); ?

Comment: I think the javascript here is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your local server is running windows which is not case sensitive and your production server is running linux which is case sensitive, check the uppercased names and see if any of them shouldn't be